# How to play mp3 file in raw folder as notification sound alert in android

Tags: android

I am having my own audio file placed in raw folder inside resource folder.I want to set it as notification sound alert. how should i proceed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please used below code when you get notification in BroadcastReceiver then call activity in that activity class used below code so play sound file.

```
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

Happy Coding..

Comment: What about the `prepare()` statement for replaying the same sound within the activity?

Comment: @Nikhil How can I do this if my platform doesn't support QCMediaPlayer? I get an error saying `QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present` when I create and instance...

Comment: You create the MediaPlayer twice in the first 2 rows. You can remove the first.

Comment: @SiKni8 when using  static method MediaPlayer.create() it call the create inside it. you shouldn't call prepare() after this.

Comment: This does not works if app removed from Background.

Comment: need to add noBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW); & NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW

Answer (score 13):

This is often achieved using the MediaPlayer but that is not an ideal solution because it runs a little independently of notifications, and therefore will behave in unexpected ways for muting, blocking mode, and various other things.  For consistency and compatibility, the sound should be played using the audio mechanism of notifications themselves.  This can be accomplished by setting an appropriate URI, along the lines of:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_myicon)
    .setContentTitle(title).setAutoCancel(true);
Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/mymp3");
builder.setSound(alarmSound);
...
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)
    getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

The key part is:

```
Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
                    + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/mymp3");
```

The mp3 file is stored in your /res/raw folder.

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
notification.sound =Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "Name OF audio store in raw folder");
```

Answer (score 2):

Refer the code

```
 Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM); 
 mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
 final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM) != 0) {
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            player.setLooping(true);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a sound using

> notification.sound =
>   Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/notification/ringer.mp3");

go through http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: `FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/MIUI/.ringtone/Kash%20Kahin.mp3 exposed beyond app through Notification.sound` getting this exception on select storage notification sound

Comment: Looks like from Android N onwards they restricted imposing file:// uri because, their reasoning make sense to me.. read here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileUriExposedException..  Looks like suggested way is to use content:// Uri instead. Example code here https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0, seems helpful for you. Please give it a try drop a not here about whether it worked.

Comment: I referred above docs not able to play sound with `content://` both `system sound` and   `storage`  (custom path) also tried with `FileProvider`. still searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can play sound from raw folder below is java file just copy paste this code implement it and use just that class's function it will play sound with loud music and with vibrate .......

if you want to vibrate also then you have to add permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Create BeepManager.java file and copy paste below code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

final class BeepManager {

 private static final String TAG = BeepManager.class.getSimpleName();
 private static final float BEEP_VOLUME = 0.10f;
 private static final long VIBRATE_DURATION = 200L;
 private final Activity activity;
 private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 private boolean playBeep;
 private boolean vibrate;

BeepManager(Activity activity) {
 this.activity = activity;
 this.mediaPlayer = null;
 updatePrefs();
}

void updatePrefs() {
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
 playBeep = shouldBeep(prefs, activity);
 vibrate = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_VIBRATE, false);
 if (playBeep && mediaPlayer == null) {
  // The volume on STREAM_SYSTEM is not adjustable, and users found it too loud,
  // so we now play on the music stream.
   activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mediaPlayer = buildMediaPlayer(activity);
 }
}

void playBeepSoundAndVibrate() {
 if (playBeep && mediaPlayer != null) {
     mediaPlayer.start();
  }
  if (vibrate) {
   Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) activity.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
   vibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_DURATION);
  }
}

 private static boolean shouldBeep(SharedPreferences prefs, Context activity) {
   boolean shouldPlayBeep = prefs.getBoolean(PreferencesActivity.KEY_PLAY_BEEP, true);
  if (shouldPlayBeep) {
    // See if sound settings overrides this
    AudioManager audioService = (AudioManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (audioService.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL) {
       shouldPlayBeep = false;
    }
  }
  return shouldPlayBeep;
}

private static MediaPlayer buildMediaPlayer(Context activity) {
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  // When the beep has finished playing, rewind to queue up another one.
  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer player) {
     player.seekTo(0);
   }
 });

 AssetFileDescriptor file = activity.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.beep);
 try {
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(), file.getStartOffset(), file.getLength());
  file.close();
  mediaPlayer.setVolume(BEEP_VOLUME, BEEP_VOLUME);
  mediaPlayer.prepare();
 } catch (IOException ioe) {
  Log.w(TAG, ioe);
  mediaPlayer = null;
 }
 return mediaPlayer;
}
}
```

Now just use following function you can play sound............

```
 BeepManager beepManager = new BeepManager(this);
 beepManager.updatePrefs();



 beepManager.playBeepSoundAndVibrate();
```

Comment: Just god know how it answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the sound in the notification message you should parse the Uri of raw file from /res/raw folder, so we do something like this:

```
.setSound(Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/notice"))
```