# How can I change alarm sound with RingtoneManager?

Tags: android, alarm, ringtonemanager

I was able to set ringtone and notification with this method:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, type, ringtoneUri)
```

But when type is `RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM`, it doesn't change the alarm sound? Do I have to do anything extra?

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.figengungor.soundboard">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your manifest.xml

Comment: Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), uri_1);
ringtone.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
ringtone.play();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set custom Alarm tone in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064519/how-to-set-custom-alarm-tone-in-android)

Comment: I just want to change default alarm sound. So all the alarms will get the sound that I set.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<uses-permission android:name="MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything. Still not able to change alarm sound.